# set column default failed in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table DDL:

```sql
-- auto-generated definition
create table treehole
(
    id          bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    content     text                                not null,
    author_id   bigint                              not null,
    create_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    modify_time timestamp                           not null,
    oo_num      int       default 0                 not null,
    xx_num      int       default 0                 not null
);

create index Treehole_author_id_index
    on treehole (author_id);

create index Treehole_create_time_index
    on treehole (create_time desc);

create index Treehole_oo_num_index
    on treehole (oo_num desc);
```

And I want to set the default of modify_time as current_timestamp:

```sql
alter table `treehole`
    alter column `modify_time`
        set default current_timestamp;
```

And it occurs:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_timestamp' at line 3
```

My MySQL version is 8.0.422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off, use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE treehole
MODIFY COLUMN modify_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The jist here is that you need `MODIFY COLUMN` rather than `ALTER COLUMN`, and also you need to basically restate the entire column definition, rather than just restating the default value.

Comment: Oops.. It works but the my SQL is created automatically by datagrip 